# Python Pandas Dataframe, remove all rows where 'None' is the value in any column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe. When it was created 'None' was used as the value where a number could not be calculated (instead of 'nan')

How can I delete all rows that have 'None' in any of it's columns? I though I could use `df.dropna` and set the value of `na`, but I can't seem to be able to.

Thanks

I think this is a good representation of the dataframe:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['str1','str2',2,3,5,6,76,8],['str3','str4',2,3,'None',6,76,8]])
```

Comment: Is it `"None"` (a string) or `None`?

Comment: Now you ask, I'm not sure. I think it's `None`, not a string

Comment: `None` is automatically replaced by `np.nan`. It's probably `"None"` that you have. Please check. The answer depends on what you have.

Comment: Paste some relevant row of your dataframe into your question.

Answer (score 54):

**Setup**
Borrowed @MaxU's `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, None, 6],
    [None, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11]
], dtype=object)
```

**Solution**
You can just use [**`pd.DataFrame.dropna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) as is

```
df.dropna()

   0   1   2
0  1   2   3
3  9  10  11
```

---

Supposing you have `None` strings like in this `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 'None', 6],
    ['None', 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11]
], dtype=object)
```

Then combine `dropna` with `mask`

```
df.mask(df.eq('None')).dropna()

   0   1   2
0  1   2   3
3  9  10  11
```

You can ensure that the entire dataframe is `object` when you compare with.

```
df.mask(df.astype(object).eq('None')).dropna()

   0   1   2
0  1   2   3
3  9  10  11
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: Could not compare ['None'] with block values` with the strings solution and a dataframe of the same size as before with the first solution

Answer (score 37):

Thanks for all your help. In the end I was able to get

`df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()`

to work. I'm not sure why your suggestions didn't work for me.

Comment: This is very useful if one has empty value for columns with str data type.

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [70]: temp[temp.astype(str).ne('None').all(1)]
Out[70]:
      0     1  2  3  4  5   6  7
0  str1  str2  2  3  5  6  76  8
```

**Old answer:**

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]:
      a     b   c
0     1     2   3
1     4  None   6
2  None     7   8
3     9    10  11

In [36]: x = x[~x.astype(str).eq('None').any(1)]

In [37]: x
Out[37]:
   a   b   c
0  1   2   3
3  9  10  11
```

or [bit nicer variant from @roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512763/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-all-rows-where-none-is-the-value-in-any-column/45512832?noredirect=1#comment77987225_45512832):

```
In [47]: x = x[x.astype(str).ne('None').all(1)]

In [48]: x
Out[48]:
   a   b   c
0  1   2   3
3  9  10  11
```

Comment: Slight aside; is there a reason for `~` + `eq` instead of just `ne`? I can't test atm but it seems from a quick search that `ne` would do the trick? I'm very much in the learning phase with pandas.

Comment: @jlt199, could you post (in your question) a small reproducible data set and your desired data set?

Comment: Working on getting a small dataset, but struggling. Please bare with me..

Comment: Did you know about `pd.DataFrame.as_blocks`?  Wow!  `df.as_blocks()['object']`

Comment: @piRSquared, wow! i've never seen it before! I'm going to dig into it...

Comment: Just in case people are finding this on a search, **N.B.** `pd.DataFrame.as_blocks` is **Deprecated since version 0.21.0.**

Answer (score 2):

im a bit late to the party, but this is prob the simplest method:

```
df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Parameters:
axis='index/column' how='any/all'

axis '0' is for dropping rows (most common), and '1' will drop columns instead.
and the parameter how will drop if there are 'any' None types in the row/ column,
or if they are all None types (how='all')

Comment: NOTE that how='any' is the default value for .dropna(), hence, this doesn't work which is precisely what @jlt199 pointed out in his question.

Answer (score 0):

if still None is not removed , we can do

`df = df.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()`

the above solution worked partially still the None was converted to NaN but not removed (thanks to the above answer as it helped to move further)
so then i added one more line of code that is take the particular column

`df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x : str(x))`

this changed the NaN to nan
now remove the nan

`df = df[df['column'] != 'nan']`