# Why doesn't this None filtering work with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

Let's say we have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, None], [None, 7]], dtype=object, columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df['a'])
# 0       1
# 1       4
# 2    None
```

I have read [Python Pandas Dataframe, remove all rows where 'None' is the value in any column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45512763/python-pandas-dataframe-remove-all-rows-where-none-is-the-value-in-any-column) and [Pandas - Filtering None Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117272/pandas-filtering-none-values), and I do know that **the solution to remove rows with `None`** is to filter the dataframe with `df[~df['a'].isnull()]`, since we have:

```
df['a'].isnull()
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
```

**Question: why don't these two pythonic-looking solutions fail?**

```
df[df['a'] != None]  # fails: filters nothing
df[df['a'] is not None]  # fails too
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because in pandas most time is possible change `None` with `NaN` both working with special function like [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), `isnull` for oldier versions.

Your solution working if test element wise:

```
df = df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: x is not None)]
```